# apt-get update not solving the issue

Tags: apt, 64-bit

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I get this every time I do something with `apt-get`. How do I get rid of this error message?

Edit:

This is what my `sources.list` looks like:

```
missingfaktor@going-merry /etc/apt/sources.list.d $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# /etc/apt/sources.list

# deb http://badgerports.org lucid main
# deb-src http://badgerports.org lucid main
# deb http://repository.glx-dock.org/ubuntu maya cairo-dock ## Cairo-Dock-Stable
```

Comment: @JorgeCastro, please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the other files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ .  Files in those folders are also used by apt-get, and it's quite likely that you have two files in that folder referencing the same PPA (or one file in there referencing it twice).